# Is it possible to precreate partitions for Windows 10 install on a dual SSD laptop?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd, efi

I have a laptop with 2 SSD.  I want to install on 1 drive, so all of the partitions: EFI, Recovery, System Reserved, main C drive to be all on this drive.  For some reasons in my case, the default install would always put the EFI on the other drive.  The easiest way would be to open up the laptop and remove the other drive, then install Windows 10, then pop the other drive back in.

Is there another way, without opening up the laptop? Is it possible to preconfigure the partitions before you boot the Windows 10 install? If so, what would be the filetype and sizes for those partitions?  The order should be something like this: System Preserved, EFI, C, Recovery? I can boot a live Linux usb, then use Gparted to partition if it is possible.

I ask because the Windows 10 install only allows you to click "New" on a drive and apply.  Then just install.. so I could not customize the partitions during the installation.

The problematic partitions are the EFI and the Recovery.  For some reasons, Windows 10 always create them on the other drive.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it would require you working through [this process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-using-a-single-wim?view=windows-11) to automatically run configuration ahead of deploying Windows. Specifically [this portion on handling the recovery and boot partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-system-and-recovery-partitions?view=windows-11) will be of interest.